# GWT local runs failed app engine server : Failed to load resource: the server :8080/slick/6E808AC.cache.js responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am working on GWT with google app engine server. My project runs successfully with GWT 2.6.1 with google app engine server.

Now I have migrated GWT 2.6.1 to 2.7 and also updated [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/)  and [GWT Eclipse Plugin](http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/).

Now I have migrated my application using using [Migrating from the Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe#gwt).

Now I am running my application on local with google app engine server first time run successfully.

Now I have added console log in gwt client side classes code then I compiled the code then again I run my application then I am getting below exception:

```
Failed to load resource: the server :8080/slick_erp/6E808ACCD5F3FBFB180586E2E5C48306.cache.js  responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Why I am getting this error?

When I deleted local server and clean the project and added server again then application run successfully  but this way not possible run every time becuase its taking too much time.

How to solve above error any help? How to run client side GWT changes on google app engine server locally?